# Google Sites App script does not work with custom domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites-2016

I have an google app script embeded in my google site web page.

It works when I call the page using the native url
https://sites.google.com/pritchardaccommodation.co.uk/wrexham/accomdetail

When I call it with the custom url https://www.pritchardaccommodation.co.uk/accomdetail

it gives the following error : 
script.google.com refused to connect.

Comment: Have you set x-frame-options to allow all?

Answer (score 2):

yes thank you postmaster that worked

> function doGet(e) {
>         return  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page").evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
>       }

but also I had to use a different url

[image]

the publish uses the URL: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyP9B95KX6hVamCmN3CKVduZm1zLKyaQTG-WDbfhXp9JcOuePs1/exec

which does not work when embedded into a site with a custom URL.

instead I clicked the "Test web app for your latest code." which gives a different URL custom domain instead.

https://script.google.com/a/pritchardaccommodation.co.uk/macros/s/AKfycbxjlbdMmWRjVUESB6hexmN34v8fw7gLfWYY0FWXz1hd/dev

and then change the "dev" on the end to "exec:

Comment: God bless you for this simple solution. Adding ".setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)" fixed the problem for me.